# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python

Помогите исправить ошибку. У меня такая ошибка:

> `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Фрагмент кода, где выдается ошибка:

```
M = 216 
t1 = np.linspace(a, b, M)
f1 = np.interp(t1, z1, a1)
f1_not_nan = f1
f1_not_nan[math.isnan(f1)] = np.array([])
```

Я думаю, что тут проблема в  `f1 = np.interp(t1, z1, a1)`, но не знаю, как именно исправить. Если есть идеи, подскажите.

Comment: а на какой строке ошибка вылазит?

Comment: ошибку выдает на строке f1_not_nan[math.isnan(f1)] = np.array([])

Comment: Уже нашла ошибку